# Can I continue a sentence after "respectively"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it okay and in common usage to continue a sentence after using the word “respectively”?  Consider this example:

> Denoting the object’s mass and acceleration by m and a, respectively, Newton’s second law can be written as F=ma.

Comment: Why would one think that it couldn't be continued?

Comment: Simply because I can't remind myself seeing it being done, and since I have had others pointing out that they are unsure whether this is okay after seeing my writing. Should I interpret this as you saying that it is okay and in common usage?

Comment: The sentence sounds perfectly alright to me, as a native speaker. It is just an adjectival clause ending with the word 'respectively', preceding the main body of the sentence.  The only alteration I would make would be to remove the comma before 'respectively', but leaving the one after it.

Comment: There's no need for the  sledge-hammer *respectively* here, because it's already obvious *m* goes with *mass* and *a* goes with *acceleration*.  Just leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine. The issue is not the adverb *respectively*, but rather the gerund-participial phrase at the beginning: *Denoting the objects mass and acceleration by m and a*. This is incomplete on its own, having no subject and no tensed verb, so it can't stand on its own, and needs a main clause to attach to. This is provided by *Newton's second law can be written as F=ma.*

Comment: Some would argue that the -ing clause is a misplaced modifier.